# python sklearn pipiline fit: "AttributeError: lower not found"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I'm trying to classify sveveral text data into 3 categories using sklearn. But I'm getting

> "AttributeError: lower not found"

when running.

**Code:**

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, random_state=42, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)
X_train = train.contents
X_test = test.contents
Y_train = train.category
Y_test = test.category

clf_svc = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=',', use_idf=True, stop_words="english")),
                    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
                    ])

clf_svc = clf_svc.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predicted_svc = clf_svc(X_test)
print(np.mean(predicted_svc == Y_test))
```

Dataframe (df) consists of 2 columns: contents (long text data) and categories (text 
data). contents are scraped texts thus contain tens or hundreds of words, and categories are single words such as "A", "B".

I've already checked past questions in stackoverflow but I could not solve this error occuring.
I'd be very glad to know the solution, or problems in the code itself.
Any advice and answers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can remove CountVectorizer all-together. TfidfVectorizer will do that for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either remove step `('vect', CountVectorizer())` or use `TfidfTransformer` instead of `TfidfVectorizer` as `TfidfVectorizer` expects array of strings as an input and  `CountVectorizer()` returns a matrix of occurances (i.e. numeric matrix).

Per default `TfidfVectorizer(..., lowercase=True)` will try to "lowercase" all strings, hence the `“AttributeError: lower not found”` error message.

Also parameter `tokenizer` expects either a callable (function) or `None`, so don't specify it.